# PHP ImageMagick Crop By Providing top/right/bottom/left Percentages

Tags: php, imagemagick, crop

I know how to crop an image using cropImage() function of ImageMagick:

```
$imagick->cropImage($width, $height, $startX, $startY);
```

How can I crop an image using PHP by providing top, right, left and bottom percentages using ImageMagick?

Comment: Get the image dimensions. Then convert the percentages to actual coordinates (`x=percent*width/100` and  `y=percent*height/100`). Then use the coordinates to compute the width and height (`width=topleftx-toprightx` and `height=bottomlefty-toplefty`). Then use cropImage as you specify above.

Comment: See also https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: @fmw42 Thank you, I solved it. Posted below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it using the following code:

```
$imagick = new Imagick;
$imagick->readImageBlob( $image );

$image_width    = $imagick->getImageWidth();
$image_height   = $imagick->getImageHeight();

$x = $image_width * ($left/100);
$y = $image_height * ($top/100);

$new_width  = $image_width - ($image_width * ($right/100)) - $x;
$new_height = $image_height - ($image_height * ($bottom/100)) - $y;

$imagick->cropImage($new_width, $new_height, $x, $y);
```